# When I edit the decrypted .csv file and put back in to clash royale the game crashes

Tags: android, csv

I'm trying to edit clash royale but whenever ı does the game crashes. What should ı do? By the way with csv files

Answer (score 1):

This might happen for a variety of reasons, but can be difficult without access to whatever you're editting. The most likely reasons are either:

- It has a MD5 checksum it checks against for tampering.
- There's a mistake in the edited file (or it's missing a specific validity check).
- The timestamp tells Clash Royale that it has been editted outside of the app.